# Python Opencv black window

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, window

Using python and `opencv` I am averaging an image over 20 images with .5 second between them. I have used this library successfully so far, but this one is giving me a problem.
This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, .2)

total = np.zeros((480,640,3), int)
time.sleep(0.500)
x = 0
while x < 19:
    retval, img = webcam.read()
    if(retval == True):
        total += img;
        time.sleep(0.500)
        x += 1

result = np.zeros((480,640,3), int)
result = np.divide(total, 20, dtype=int)

cv2.namedWindow("result",cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.cv.MoveWindow("result", 0, 0)
while True:
    cv2.imshow("result", result)
    if(cv2.waitKey(10) == 27):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
webcam.release()
```

Whilst running this program gives no error, it does display a black image.
The `img` variable returns a working image however.
The averaging probably creates the error here, but as far as I know the contents of the result matrix is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix **`np.uint8`** and **`int32`** in OpenCV, which causes *All Blacks* to appear.

While you need for sure an accumulator array **`total`** to have sufficient bit-depth for an incremental **`+=`** summing phase, but your **`np.divide()`**, which you want to pass to a `cv2.imshow()` **shall** result in display-able **`dtype = np.uint8`**

```
result = np.zeros( (480,640,3),        np.uint8 )    # needless to pre-allocate
result = np.divide( total, 20, dtype = np.uint8 )    # just enough to assign here
```

---

n.b.1:

You might also note a typo in double **`.set()`** which does not make any issue if `VideoCapture()` device still returns array of `(480,640,3) np.uint8`-s

```
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
#                                   |||||  ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the solution. I still have trouble understanding data types in python, because they are not so clear as other languages I work with. But there is one flaw, the `np.divide()` makes the `total` a `uint8` **before it divides**, so I need to divide it first, and then convert to the `uint8`.

Comment: You may notice,that **`python`** has nothing to do with the data types. Python language is not strong typed. The **`numpy/openCV`** do care. That is due to their internal behaviour of C-language based matrix manipulation engine, that gets via a **`dtype=`** named-parameter an important piece of information about a cell-type/size, that is usefull for a **most efficient** memory-alignment of the cells, keeping in mind their respective size, so as to maximise CPU-Cache/MEM-Cache hits during calculations and thus having the **minimum** possible processing time / **highest** achievable performance.